# Images from Firebase Storage in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I am beginner in iOS and Swift. I want to display images from Firebase Storage.
According to the tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

This is how it should be done in View Controller

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

as far as I know there is no View Controller in SwiftUI.

The question is how to put UIImageView into Image

What I tried to do is

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseStorageUI

struct StorageImage: View {
    
    private let path: String
    let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()


    init(path: String) {
        self.path = path
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        let reference = storageRef.child(path)
        let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if (self.imageView.image != nil) {
            Image(uiImage: self.imageView.image!)
        }
        
    }
}
```

But it looks like the image is nil

Comment: You can get a URL from Storage and use it with AsyncImage. You are trying to mix UIKit with SwiftUI unnecessarily.

Comment: But what about the cache? Whenever user goes to the view with the list of the images I need to do multiple calls for download url. I understand that FirebaseUI keeps images in cache and uses path as a key

Comment: @TomaszIwaszko look up SDWebImageSwiftUI - it can help with what you want for caching images.